# Git init -q Permissions error while installing Homebrew

Tags: permissions, homebrew, macos-sierra

I'm attempting to install HomeBrew on OS X 10.12.6. When I use the autoinstall script from Homebrew's website:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Everything runs smoothly until it begins actually downloading and installing Homebrew, at which point it returns the following error:

```
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
/usr/local/homebrew/.git: Permission denied
Failed during: git init -q
```

Any tips of how to resolve this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You should make your /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/opt writeable, i.e.:

```
chmod +w /usr/local/bin
chmod +w /usr/local/opt
```

Depending on your user's permissions you may have to use *sudo* to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe git is missing:

> apt install git